# Delphi exponentially slow opening a many-columns dataset

Tags: database, performance, delphi

I wonder if anyone has experienced this problem that has been increasingly annoying me recently.
Let's say I have a 100+ columns table. When I need to select one record from  it takes ridiculous amount of time. 
Looking at the debugger I can narrow it down to binding the fields in db.pas.
Apparently for each field, it kills and rebuilds the internal field definitions list.
I usually workaround this by keeping the dataset alive and refreshing it with new key field values. Regret it does not work with the aducom sqlite component.

[image]

Steps to reproduce:

Code:

```
procedure TForm6.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: string;
  i, n, j: Integer;
  tick: DWORD;
begin
  for j := 0 to 10 do begin
    N := 1 shl j;
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Columns count: ' + IntToStr(N));

    ASQLite3Query1.SQL.Text := 'drop table if exists test';
    ASQLite3Query1.ExecSQL;
    s := '';
    for i := 1 to N do
      s := s + 'field' + IntToStr(i) + ' integer' + IfThen(i<n, ',');
    ASQLite3Query1.SQL.Text := 'create table test(' + s + ');';
    ASQLite3Query1.ExecSQL;

    ASQLite3Query1.SQL.Text := 'select * from test';
    tick := GetTickCount;
    ASQLite3Query1.Open;
    ASQLite3Query1.Close;
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Time elapsed, ms: ' + IntToStr(GetTickCount - tick));
  end;
  Timer1.Enabled := false;
end;
```

Output:

```
Columns count: 1
Time elapsed, ms: 0
Columns count: 2
Time elapsed, ms: 0
Columns count: 4
Time elapsed, ms: 0
Columns count: 8
Time elapsed, ms: 0
Columns count: 16
Time elapsed, ms: 0
Columns count: 32
Time elapsed, ms: 0
Columns count: 64
Time elapsed, ms: 31
Columns count: 128
Time elapsed, ms: 94
Columns count: 256
Time elapsed, ms: 203
Columns count: 512
Time elapsed, ms: 671
Columns count: 1024
Time elapsed, ms: 4976
```

EDIT: I incorrectly used the word "exponentially". The function between fields count and time appears to be quadratic (give or take relative size of FieldDefs and CPU cache).

Comment: What Delphi version? I have noticed similar issues when attempting to migrate from XE2 to XE3. We canceled that update because our TClientDataSets became horribly slow.

Comment: Does your dataset use persistent TFields, or do you allow it to create them dynamically when it is opened?

Comment: Is Delphi slow, or is aducom sqllite slow? I think you need to do some more investigation to narrow down the problem. At least provide a short sample to reproduce the problem in isolation from the rest of the rest of your system.

Comment: About my comment regarding XE3: [Google "tclientdataset very slow in xe3 update"](https://www.google.nl/search?q=tclientdataset+very+slow+in+xe3+update)

Comment: D2007. Same with persistent or dynamic fields. Delphi is slow but aducom prevents me from using sql params + refresh in an efficient manner.

Comment: Now that you've added sample code to demonstrate the problem, the question is significantly improved. However, I do consider it a little alarmist to claim Delphi is exponentially slow given your sample stats. E.g. 128:94 --> 256:203 Doubling inputs also doubles duration; which is to be expected. The final jump is bigger than expected: 2xInputs, 7xDuration (but still not exponential). That said, next comment will offer a few general tips you could try....

Comment: **1)** First and foremost: stop using `SELECT * ...`! It's a bad idea when your underlying table has 10 columns. It's a much worse idea when have over 100 columns. _Only get the columns you need._ **2)** Do you really need that many columns on a table? Surely there's a way to restructure your data into more manageable chunks. Large numbers of columns will also make it more difficult for the RDBMS to manage the data efficiently: More columns -> More data per row -> Less rows per page -> Less efficient indexing and storage.

Comment: **3)** Use persistent fields so that instead of Delphi dynamically generating fields from meta-data, it simply binds existing fields to the corresponding underlying columns. **4)** Use a parameterised query. I.e. keep a query object correctly defined, with correct fields so this doesn't need to be recreated. Whenever you get a different row, you simply change your parameter value before getting the row. _The bonus effects of this are that you usually end up with cleaner code and provide opportunities for your RDBMS to do some things more efficiently._

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Too bad all your advice is irrelevant to this case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the Aducom components so I can't give you a "how to guide" that I can test, but I've set up a testbed using a TClientDataSet and would suggest the following.  I'm assuming your TAsqlite3Query does not have any calculated, lookup or aggregate fields (but if it does the following applies to them, too).

- Put a breakpoint on DB.TDataSet.BindFields, compile and run.
- When the breakpoint triggers, single-step through BindFields, and trace into everything it calls.
- While tracing into calls from BindFields, note the effects of whether the dataset has persistent TFields *and* persistent TFieldDefs.  All TDataSet descendants implement persistent TFields but not all implement persistent TFieldDefs, and I don't know whether the Aducom ones do or not.

Analysing those steps, should give you a clearer idea of what effect persistent TFields and persistent TFieldDefs (if available) have on execution speed of DoBindFields and may help your profiling zero-in on possible pinchpoints if it isn't already clear whether your code would benefit from persistent TFields and/or persistent TFieldDefs.

Comment: The attached picture shows that I already did that - it's slow because it clears and rebuilds the internal list twice per each field in the dataset. Persistent fields save some execution time as it skips the CreateFields routine but that is not the main culprit here.

Comment: Sorry, I thought your picture was from the debugger.  Have you done any actual profiling or not?

Comment: Sorry, is there a misunderstanding? I already found the bottleneck. My question is how to work around it